# Ошибки при сборке проекта с SQLite

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite

Подключаю:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlite3.c"
```

Ошибки в sqlite.c:

```
невозможно преобразовать "void *" в "sqlite3_mutex *"
невозможно преобразовать "void *" в "char *"
```

и т.д.

Что я сделал:
Указал чтобы sqllite.c компилировался в  "С";  Отключил CLR; Отключил предварительно  скомпилированные заголовки.

Это не помогло

Comment: Видимо, тот файл, где вы написали `#include "sqlite3.c"`, компилируется как С++. Я бы на вашем месте сделал отдельный таргет в проекте, состоящий только из sqlite3.c, и добавлял бы референсы на него в тех таргетах, где используется sqlite